# Snap element near where cursor is hovering

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, user-interface

I would like to make a web interface where an arrow or some kind of place marker (a triangle in my mock-up below) jumps in increments vertically following the user's cursor. It will be for desktop only, so mobile is not a concern.

The goal is for the marker to snap to "insertion points" where the user can then click to add a new element to some list of items. Think of it as a tool for composing web content. The marker shows where it is possible to add an element (in between other elements).

The trouble is, web searches haven't turned up anything quite like this. I don't really know what to call it, except maybe a "snap hover" or "notched slider" effect.

Mock-up:

[image: mock-up of the notched snap hover effect]

The marker should only interact with the cursor within a certain proximity (for example 50 pixels), so that the marker will only move when that is the user's intention. It should stay locked in place while a new element is being added, until the user either chooses "OK" or "Cancel". These are details though - the main thing is I don't know how to code the snapping effect based on the cursor position.

I'm open to both jQuery and vanilla js solutions.

Comment: Please show us what you have tried.

Comment: try this example, can help you : http://jsfiddle.net/becher_henchiri/ys7bzjqr/1/

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate positions and sizes of your items and then just highlight one with shortest distance to cursor position:

```js
function chooseNearest(items, cursorPosition) {
  const { y } = cursorPosition;

  return items
    .map(
      ({ top, height }) => top + height / 2
    ).reduce(
      ({ distance, itemIndex }, center, index) => {
        const newDistance = Math.abs(y - center);

        return newDistance < distance
          ? { distance: newDistance, itemIndex: index }
          : { distance, itemIndex };
      }, ({ distance: Infinity })
    )
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but can you please explain how your code works? (I am especially confused by→ distance: Infinity) Also, you stated that "you can calculate positions and sizes of your items" but I don't know what that step would look like.

Comment: `Infinity` - is a number value, represents infinity (so, `Infinity` is always greater then any other number). To calculate element positions and height you can use `element.getBoundingClientRect()`